# Random divider image between posts

Tags: php, wordpress, image, echo, divider

for my wordpress based website I would like to display a random image between posts, not having an image after the last post.

I thought I could combine an echo inside a php, but it would appear that this is impossible.

Any ideas how to accomplish this ?

```
<?php
if (($wp_query->current_post + 1) < ($wp_query->post_count)) {
echo '<div class="post-item-divider" align="center"><img     src="http://v2.fortherestless.com/images/clouds/<?php echo rand(1,20);?>.png" alt="Random Image" /></div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the number first in a variable then insert it to the image url.

```
<?php
if (($wp_query->current_post + 1) < ($wp_query->post_count)) {
$image_num = rand(1, 20);
echo '<div class="post-item-divider" align="center"><img src="http://v2.fortherestless.com/images/clouds/' . $image_num . '.png" alt="Random Image" /></div>';
}
?>
```